# scrbook - Start chapters without \cleardoublepage and \clearpage

Tags: chapters, scrbook, clearpage

I am a business student and use LaTeX for quite some time already and love it, but my understanding of coding is limited, so please bare with me if I make inaccurate statements.

I am currently writing my thesis and for space reasons need to eliminate the fact that each chapter only starts on a new page.

I have read through the entire forum and tried maybe... 10 (?) different approaches, but none of them help. Most do nothing, some just delete all the content of the chapter, without actually moving it to the previous (half finished) page.

I hope someone can help me. I use a template I found online and have a folder structure (one for chapters, one for text, one for settings...), so it could be that there are some things somewhere defined, which don't let me override the start of a new page for each chapter, but I cannot for the life of me figure out if so and where. Maybe you could give me pointers to that? Words to search for? I would of course report back the sections.

I am using this:

```
\documentclass[
      paper=a4,
      12pt,
      twoside=false,
      openright,
]{scrbook}
```

and work with:

```
\include{chapters/c1_Einleitung.tex}
...
```

and have all the chapters in their own tex files.

I define the chapters/thesis in "c0" as well as a "settings" file. However there are other files too, which I haven't touched and supposingly do something.

I hope someone can help me.

I literally just want chapters to NOT start a new page, but none of the fixes provided online seem to work.

Best regards
Niklas

Comment: `\include` will use `\clearpage` (has to to function correctly) so there is no way you'll get "same page" with this. You could use `\input` instead of `\include` to not have that issue. Then try the fixes you found earlier and see whether they do. If not, please provide a minimal example showing your issue.

Comment: Thank you for this, I am using \input now and am trying the solution below before retrying all the other approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=section]{chapter}
```

to the preamble and replace `\include` by `\input`.

Example:

```latex
% to provide the dummy files c1.tex and c2.tex:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{c1.tex}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{c2.tex}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[3-5]
\end{filecontents}

% document:
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt, twoside=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=section]{chapter}% <- added
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\input{c1}% <- changed to \input
\input{c2}% <- changed to \input
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Additional example because of the comments (Disclaimer: I do not like the result)

```latex
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt, twoside=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  beforeskip=15pt,
  afterskip=15pt,
  afterindent=false,
  font=\Large
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1em,
  afterskip=1em,
  afterindent=false,
  font=\large
]{section}

\renewcommand{\chapterformat}{\thechapter\autodot\quad\hspace{1em}}
\renewcommand{\sectionformat}{\thesection\autodot\quad\hspace{1.4em}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionformat}{\thesection\autodot\quad\hspace{.6em}}

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalcolor\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it did exactly what I wanted. However now the new headline is gigantic. I made two screenshots, but I fail to find where to include an image. So I uploaded it: https://i.ibb.co/1bfxTf1/bold-font.png 

I have checked if there are some definitions to what a section should look like, but no matter how I changed it, it had no effect. Here are the definitions I found by searching for "section":

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Large\bfseries}{\thechapter\quad}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\large\bfseries}{\thesection\quad}{1.4em}{}

Comment: I was unable to include all in one answer, p2:

\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection\quad}{0.6em}{}
  
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-16pt}{16pt}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{1em}{1em}


\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalcolor\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{0pt}} 
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace*{15pt}} 


This is what I found additionally (some already included above) for "chapter":

\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}
\renewcommand*{\indexpagestyle}{scrheadings}


Any ideas?

Best regards
Niklas

Comment: Maybe I should also add, that I liked the old style of the headline, the new one appears way too big in my opinion (also in terms of "saving space")

Comment: Do *not* use package `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class. In your code snippets there is a  crazy mixure of `titlesec` settings and KOMA-Script settings. You can change the layout of the chapter title etc. using `\RedeclareSectionCommand`. 

And please: If you ask a question please add a minimal working example to the question.

Comment: I have added an additional example using `beforeskip`, `font` etc. in the opitonal argument of `\RedeclareSectionCommand`.

Comment: I am sorry I have weird code, I just got it from the internet. I have deleted the "titlesec" part now and added your part. It works perfectly for me. I am adjusting the skips to my liking and it works like a charm. I understand you don't like it, because it's messy, but like I said, it's difficult for me to understand all the code at all times, so I am very happy it's working and I understand how to change what. Thank you so much for your feedback, it really works perfect for me!